# when checking if a checkbox has been checked or not I got a null object

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to see if a row has been selected or not by using a checkbox.  The row is inside of a ListView.  I got a null object error.

```
<td>
   <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox1" runat="server"
                 value='<%# Eval("rdvId") %>'
                 AutoPostBack="true"
                 OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"/>
</td>

protected void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int KeyId = 0;

    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
        /*     if (((CheckBox)item.FindControl("MyCheckBox")).Checked) */
        CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
        if (myCheckBox.Checked)     //      <===  generate a null object.
        {
            KeyRdvId = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Value); 
               // ( I want to get the key of the selected listview) 
        }
    }
}
```

I used this code in the procedure protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
and it works there !!!

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iCptCheckBox = 0;
    int indxChkBox = 0;

    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {

        var chk = item.FindControl("MyCheckBox") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox;
        if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
        {
            indxChkBox = Convert.ToInt32(chk.Value);//  <==== here it is working
```

Any idea why it is not working in the first one ?

Comment: `FindControl("MyCheckBox");` returns null (the name isn't even correct!) just as the error indicates. (It could be that the check box only occurs in *some* items..)

Comment: MyCheckBox or CheckBox1 ?

Comment: looks like one of the items in `ListView1.Items` doesn't have a control named `MyCheckBox`, so you'll need to add the null check (like the second block has)

Comment: Just as a future note, you're much more likely to get quality help if you post code that compiles (or would compile with minimum effort) If you want to add comments to your code to help us understand what is going on, that is great, but actually put them in either line-style `//` comments or block-style `/* ... */` comments (assuming you're posting C# code -- if not, use the comments that are appropriate for the language you are posting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a control with id `MyCheckBox` but if you look at your asp code the id is `CheckBox1` change your code to the following:

```
    CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    if (myCheckBox.Checked)         //  <===  generate a null object.
    {
        KeyRdvId = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Value); 
          //  ( I want to get the key of the selected listview) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

checkbox do not have value property.

A CheckBox is by definition a boolean and is identified by its ID. All you need to do is check whether it was checked or not.

if you really need to assign a value to checkbox, you may use `InputAttributes`:

To add:

```
myChk.InputAttributes.Add("value", "My Value");
```

to access value:

```
myChk.InputAttributes["value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar screen once and I found it the best to deal with using segregation of responsibility. in other words I made a child control and placed that in the list box, then I mapped a property to the control and made the control deal with the logic needed for the control.